# How can I display taxes in magento products and catalog seperated from the price

Tags: tax

How can I display taxes in magento products and catalog seperated from the price. Right now I can either display prices excluding or including tax from admin. I want to have an excluded price and the seperated tax amount being displayed. So not the price including tax.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

That's not a feature we support in Magento 1x.

If you want to do something like that Magento 2.x should be much easier to customize as we've streamlined/simplified the price templates and the tax engine is much easier to customize/etc.  Magento 1.x would be difficult as there are numerous price templates you'd have to refactor to display.